# install OpenCV3 on MaxOSX10.12.4 successfully but it doesn't work

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

I installed OpenCV3 with brew follow other's guide on the Internet,

## 1,install brew

```
usrs/local/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

## 2,then I install OpenCV3

```
brew install opencv3
```

## 3,after install, my path of OpenCV3 is

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0
#in fact this path "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0" contains all 
software installed by brew, and I have also try 
to install opencv, 
its path is "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13.2"
```

## 4, setup my ~/.bash_profile file

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"

# Homebrew
#export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# OpenCV3
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv3/bin:$PATH"
```

## 5.1,add "lib" and "include" path to my Xcode(version 8.3.1, 8E1000a)

[add openCV3 to "Header search paths" and "Library search Paths"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L187D.png)

## 5.2,and add something in "Build Phases" Tab

[add many opencv's dylib files(which themselves in "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13.2/lib") and three C++ dynamic linking files here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9IyR.png)

## 6, some thing wrong happened when I run my C++ code

```
Mat cv_input_image = imread("image_0001.jpg");
cout << "rows:" << cv_input_image.rows << endl;
cout << "cols:" << cv_input_image.cols << endl;
cout << "channels:" << cv_input_image.channels() << endl;
```

## it run successfully but the result is worng:

```
rows:0
cols:0
channels:1
```

## my effort:

I have try many times to install OpenCV with brew and different setup method in my Macbook(I am new in Mac), all of then didn't work well, and I can successfully include  and others about OpenCV, I just don't know where I could start to solve this problems?

by the way, I have also try my openCV(not openCV3), I can include them in my C++ code successfully

## and I have a complicated C++ code, the first step is to read a picture ,and there has an "error information":

```
inline
MatConstIterator::MatConstIterator(const Mat* _m)
    : m(_m), elemSize(_m->elemSize()), ptr(0), sliceStart(0), sliceEnd(0)
{
    if( m && m->isContinuous() )
    {
        sliceStart = m->ptr();
        sliceEnd = sliceStart + m->total()*elemSize;
    }
    seek((const int*)0);//   <=======something wrong here
}
```

my Xcode gives me information:

```
Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC(code=EXC_I386_DIV, subcode=0x0)
```

in the left of my Xcode, there has a Threads list form index 0 to 9,

## and when this happened, An arrow point to index 1:"cv::MatConstIterator::MatConstIterator(cv::Mat const*)"

wish for your help~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiled with Xcode, the executable is put in some weird temp folder. Therefore `imread("image_0001.jpg")` will most likely fail since you use relative path here (i.e. `image_0001.jpg` needs to be at the same folder as the executable. To fix this, try to use the absolute path to the image, i.e. `/Users/your_home/Desktop/image_0001.jpg`.

The other error might due to the fact that `cv_image_input` is empty after the failed `imread`.

Comment: Thanks a lot~~~~it is that problem you said